# Checking for greater than on a generic tuple element

Tags: scala

I have a method to add different types of tuples to a list with the first tuple element always being an Int. I need to do a "greater than" compare but this is not allowed on an Any type. Can someone tell me how I could achieve the desired effect below?

Thanks 
Des

```
private def add(list: List[Product], item: Product): List[Product] = {
  if(list.isEmpty || list.head.productElement(0) > item.productElement(0)) item :: list
  else add(list.tail, item)
}
```

Comment: Can't you make the type more specific? Are all tuples of the same length, then maybe `(Int,Any,Any,...)`?

Comment: This is the sort of problem where HList is much easier to work with than tuples. I suggest looking into using that instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't take [ziggystar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108915/ziggystar)'s suggestion because the `Producer` has variable arity, you could potentially achieve the desired effect by refactoring with the upside of avoiding a complex and potentially less readable approach. For instance:

```
case class Item(i: Int, item: Product)

def add(list: List[Item], item: Item): List[Item] = {
  if (list.isEmpty || list.head.i > item.i) item :: list
  else add(list.tail, item)
}
```

which, when used, looks like this:

```
add(Nil, Item(1, (1, "b"))) // List(Item(1,(1,b)))
add(List(Item(1, (1, "a"))), Item(2, (1, "b"))) // List(Item(2,(1,b)))
add(List(Item(2, (1, "a"))), Item(1, (1, "b"))) // List(Item(1,(1,b)), Item(2,(1,a))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to resort to reflection, you can use a mixture of nominal and structural typing:

```
import scala.language.reflectiveCalls

// A structural type exploiting the fact that all tuples have a _1 field
type IntComponent = { val _1: Int }

def add(list: List[Product with IntComponent], item: Product with IntComponent): List[Product with IntComponent] = {
  if(list.isEmpty || list.head._1 > item._1) item :: list
  else add(list.tail, item)
}
```

The combination `Product with IntComponent` is not strictly necessary, `IntComponent` would suffice. However, the combination gives you a bit more safety, and it allows you to use fields and methods declared by `Product` if need be.

This gives you quite a bit of static type safety:

```
add(Nil, (1, "foo", null)) // ok

add(Nil, ("foo", 0)) // error
  // error: type mismatch;
  //    found   : String("foo")
  //    required: Int

add(List[Product with IntComponent](Tuple1(1), Tuple2(-1, true)), (0, "yes"))
  // Explicit type annotation required, error otherwise
  //     found   : List[Product with Serializable]
  //     required: List[Product with this.IntComponent]
```

The obvious weakness of this approach is, that you can sneak in any object that is a `Product with IntComponent`, for example

```
case class FakeTupleA(_1: Int)

add(Nil, FakeTupleA(99)) // ok
```

Without the `Product` requirement, the following would also work:

```
add(Nil, new FakeTupleB(99))
  // error: type mismatch;
    // found   : this.FakeTupleB
    // required: Product with this.IntComponent
```

Comment: After giving it some thought wouldn't it suffice to compare the hash codes of the two objects? As a hash code of a numeric value is always the numeric value itself?

Comment: @user79074 Hm, maybe. You could also just cast `productElement(0)` to `Int` and then compare it. However, both approaches give you no static type safety whatsoever.